# Entropy of Data

Tags: python-3.x, entropy

I am new to python and entropy (using for decision trees, also new to) and I am trying to figure out how to calculate it the specific sets of data. I understand the formula in general, but I don't know how to use it in practice. For example, if I am given a file(200 entries) with the first number being x, second number is y, and the last number is the class label(0 or 1):

```
10.58,-0.055609,1
10.813,0.77631,1
8.7405,1.2628,1
```

How would I calculate the entropy of that?
And another file(8,134 entries):

```
Platform,Year_of_Release,Genre,Publisher,NA_sales,EU_Sales,JP_sales,Other_Sales,Global_Sales,Developer,Rating,Critic_Score
PS3,2013,Racing,Deep Silver,0.02,0.01,0,0.01,0.04,"Eutechnyx, Deep Silver",M,13
PS3,2013,Adventure,Codemasters,0.06,0.03,0,0.01,0.1,Team 17,M,17
XB,2002,Misc,Infogrames,0.16,0.05,0,0.01,0.22,Data Design Interactive,E,19
```

How would I calculate the entropy for this file

Comment: What definition of entropy are you using?

Comment: @kaya3 entropy = summation of -p(x)log(p(x))

Comment: OK, and what is it a sum over?

Comment: @kaya3 x, the number of entries/values.

Comment: OK, and what are the entries/values `x`, and what is `p(x)` for each of them?

Comment: @kaya3 the frequency and the current node/value

Comment: OK, and what are they for this data?

Comment: @kaya3 I guess the frequency of a 0 or a 1 class label and the current value is whatever the x and y is for the first file. I don't know about the second file.

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't have a clear enough idea of what you're trying to do. If you wouldn't be able to calculate the entropy by hand (with the help of a calculator, of course), then you won't be able to write a program to do it either. So I recommend studying some examples of how entropy is calculated using the definition you are working with.

Comment: @kaya3 Well, that was the point of me asking the question, but after reading some more, wouldn't the entropy of the first file be something like the entropy of the frequency of the values that have class label 1 vs class label 0? After that I am not sure what to do with the values of x and y themselves. Do I split them apart and calculate the entropy of the frequencies of numbers that are positive vs negative, then greater than 0 but less than 1, greater than 1 but less than 2, etc. I guess I would start in a similar position for the second file with the platform (PS3, XB, etc.)?

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow can't tell you what you are trying to do; only you are able to know that.

Comment: @kaya3 Does my previous comment seem like I am on the right track? I am modeling what I am doing on the following articles:                                                             [link](https://medium.com/@rakendd/building-decision-trees-and-its-math-711862eea1c0)                           [link](https://medium.com/@rakendd/decision-tree-from-scratch-9e23bcfb4928)

Comment: I have no idea whether you are on the right track towards solving your problem, because you have not described specifically enough what problem you are trying to solve. It looks like you are thinking about the right things, at least.

Comment: @kaya3 I added links to the previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Entropy is defined for a *distribution* of message probabilities. Talking about entropy of a finite data stream makes no sense.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.